# Scrolling Telerik RadTextBox When Needed - Not RadTextBoxControl

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, telerik, radtextbox

I'll try and explain what I'm after.
I have a multiline RadTextBox, (takes about 7 lines of text). I do n't want to show scroll bars as I start to type.
When the text gets to the 8th line either via enter or wordwrap to make the vertical scroll bar appear.

I can do this with a `RadRichTextbox` or `RadTextBoxControl`, but need to use a `RadTextBox`.
Is this possible?
I have tried using the .lines property but that doesn't increment when using word wrap.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

RadTextBox from the Telerik UI for WinForms suite internally hosts the standard MS TextBox. Hence, if you want to scroll the multiline text in it, you should do it in a similar way as in the MS TextBox. The TextBox.[ScrollBars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.scrollbars?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_TextBox_ScrollBars) Property controls which scroll bars should appear in a multiline TextBox control. You can set it to ScrollBars.Vertical. Then, you can either use the up/down arrow buttons on the keyboard or the vertical scrollbar to navigate through the multiple lines:

```
        this.radTextBox1.Multiline = true; 
        this.radTextBox1.AutoSize = false;
        this.radTextBox1.Size = new Size(50, 50);
        this.radTextBox1.TextBoxElement.TextBoxItem.TextBoxControl.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
```

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBYiC.gif)

I hope this information helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But you did n't notice on --When Needed--, i do n't want to show scrollbars at the beginning.